# Can't set permissions on Filenet P8 folder

Tags: security, authorization, filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine, content-platform-engine

In my current project using Filenet P8 Content Platform Engine 5.2.1 with WebSphere 8.5.5.3, Eclipse Mars 4.5.2 and Apache Maven 3.3.1

I'm trying to add some permissions to an existing folder using the following code:

```
public Folder addFolderPermissions(Folder folder) {

    AccessPermission permission = Factory.AccessPermission.createInstance();
    permission.set_GranteeName("AMM_000072_00001");
    permission.set_AccessType(AccessType.ALLOW);
    permission.set_InheritableDepth(-1);
    permission.set_AccessMask(EcmFilenetConsts.ACCESS_READ_FOLDER);
    AccessPermissionList permissions = folder.get_Permissions();
    permissions.add(permission);
    folder.set_Permissions(permissions);
    folder.save(RefreshMode.REFRESH);

    return folder;
}
```

where `EcmFilenetConsts.ACCESS_READ_FOLDER = AccessRight.READ.getValue() | AccessRight.READ_ACL.getValue();`

The folder has been retrieved using the following code:

```
String folderID = "{7084AE5B-0000-C817-9E59-B09C18C55230}";
PropertyFilter pf = new PropertyFilter();    
pf.addIncludeProperty(new FilterElement(null, null, null, "Permissions", null));
Folder folder = Factory.Folder.fetchInstance(objectStore, folderID, pf);
```

The problem is that when `folder.save` instruction is performed I get the following error:

```
com.filenet.api.exception.EngineRuntimeException: FNRCE0051E: E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND: The requested item was not found. propertyName=Permissions, referenced principal=AMM_000072_00001 in Domain {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} failedBatchItem=0 errorStack={
    at com.filenet.engine.security.SecurityProvider.getSecurityId(SecurityProvider.java:454)
    at com.filenet.engine.security.SecurityProvider.preGetSecurityId(SecurityProvider.java:288)
    at com.filenet.engine.security.SecurityDescriptor.updateOrCreateAce(SecurityDescriptor.java:907)
    at com.filenet.engine.security.SecurityDescriptor.updateAccessPermissionList(SecurityDescriptor.java:713)
    at com.filenet.engine.security.AccessManager.createPersistableSDFromUpdate(AccessManager.java:173)
    at com.filenet.engine.persist.IndependentPersister.preChangeSecurity(IndependentPersister.java:1743)
    at com.filenet.engine.persist.IndependentPersister.executeChange(IndependentPersister.java:329)
    at com.filenet.engine.persist.SubscribablePersister.executeChange(SubscribablePersister.java:177)
    at com.filenet.engine.jca.impl.RequestBrokerImpl.executeChanges(RequestBrokerImpl.java:1487)
    at com.filenet.engine.jca.impl.RequestBrokerImpl.executeChanges(RequestBrokerImpl.java:1345)
    at com.filenet.engine.ejb.EngineCoreBean._executeChanges(EngineCoreBean.java:619)
    at com.filenet.engine.ejb.EngineCoreBean.executeChanges(EngineCoreBean.java:586)
    at com.filenet.engine.ejb.EJSLocalStatelessEngineCore_22877cb1.executeChanges(Unknown Source)
    at com.filenet.engine.ejb.EngineBean.executeChanges(EngineBean.java:913)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.transport.ejbstubs.EJSLocalStatelessEngine_2e64c374.executeChanges(Unknown Source)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.transport.ejb.EnginePortLocal.executeChanges(EnginePortLocal.java:53)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.wsi.ServiceSessionNst$2.run(ServiceSessionNst.java:1360)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:314)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:573)
    at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:195)
    at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:152)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor47.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.util.J2EEUtilWS.doAs(J2EEUtilWS.java:239)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.wsi.ServiceSessionNst.sMakeInternalEJBCall(ServiceSessionNst.java:1223)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.wsi.ServiceSessionNst.sHandleIncomingRequest(ServiceSessionNst.java:1067)
    at com.filenet.engine.wsi.ListenerNst.service(ListenerNst.java:179)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1227)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:458)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1032)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:909)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture$1.run(AsyncChannelFuture.java:205)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
}
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.wsi.serialization.core.ExceptionSerialization.deserialize(ExceptionSerialization.java:196)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.wsi.ServiceSessionNst.cDeserializeSoapFault(ServiceSessionNst.java:693)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.wsi.ServiceSessionNst.cReqRespPath(ServiceSessionNst.java:223)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.wsi.ServiceSessionNst.executeChanges(ServiceSessionNst.java:85)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.util.SessionHandle.executeChanges(SessionHandle.java:112)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.core.Session.callExecuteChanges(Session.java:146)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.core.Session.executeChanges(Session.java:532)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.core.Session.executeChange(Session.java:850)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.core.IndependentlyPersistableObjectImpl.save(IndependentlyPersistableObjectImpl.java:76)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.core.IndependentlyPersistableObjectImpl.save(IndependentlyPersistableObjectImpl.java:67)
    at com.leonardo.spcic.ecm.filenet.security.SecurityManagerImpl.addFolderPermissions(SecurityManagerImpl.java:44)
    at com.leonardo.spcic.ecm.filenet.security.SecurityManagerImplTest.testAddFolderPermissions(SecurityManagerImplTest.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

I also tried setting a null propertyFilter for the fetch method but the error still persists.

I followed [this set permission example](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/teraxas/KKBK4/revisions/5b565d77c4fbae167e0a0109eee45b59942e8b11).

Could anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this error has anything to do with `Permissions` property. It is fetched automatically for methods like `get_Permissions()` to work unconditionally.

What is not found is the principal `AMM_000072_00001`. Are you sure that it exists in the directory service employed by P8 Domain? Is that a complete and valid ID to use as a reference?

Comment: Thanks @fnt, you were completely right. This principal was accidentally deleted (along with many others) from LDAP. After creating the group again everything works fine.